# how to pass a javascript variable to onMouseOver event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How can i use a js variable in mouseOver event?

Here is my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
              window.String1 = <%=GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String1")%>;
              window.String2 = <%=GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String2")%>;
              </script>
              <label runat="server" id="labelWeight" onmouseout="HelpOut(this);" onmouseover="Help(this,window.String1,window.String2);">
                  <asp:Localize ID="LocPWeight" runat="server" meta:Resourcekey="ProductWeightInGrams"
                            Text="Product Weight in Grams"></asp:Localize>
                </label>
```

and it looks like it doesn't work this way :).

Thanks.
!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out i needed qoutes:

```
        window.String1 = <%=GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String1")%>;
```

has to be

```
        window.String1 = '<%=GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String1")%>';
```

Your soulutions didn't work. If the label contains a runat="server" attribute "<%= %>" tags are not allowed. That's why i didn't use it in the first place, but i forgot to mention it. Sorry for that.

Thanks you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onmouseover='function(){Help(this,<%= GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String1") %>,<%= GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String2") %>);}'
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. Did you test it? The quotes are escaping the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onmouseover = 'Help(this,<%=GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String1")%>, <%=GetLocalResourceStringEscaped("String2")%>);';
```